# How do i call a method by a string name using python?

Tags: python, function

I have the following class;

```
class myStringMethod():
    def __init__(self):
        self.func_list= [('func1','print_func1()'),('func2','print_func2()')]

    def print_func1(self, name):
        print name

    def print_func2(self, name):
        print name

    def call_func_by_name(self):
        for func in self.func_list:
            getattr(self, func[1])('Func Name')

if __name__=='__main__':
    strM = myStringMethod()
    strM.call_func_by_name() #Nothing prints out!
```

No functions get called out, what am i missing?

gath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `self.func_list` should be:

```
self.func_list= [('func1','print_func1'),('func2','print_func2')]
```

And the way your code is written it will, of course, print `'Func Name'`. I guess you probably meant to pass `func[0]` there.

Working example:

```
>>> class myStringMethod():
    def __init__(self):
        self.func_list= [('func1','print_func1'),('func2','print_func2')]

    def print_func1(self, name):
        print(name)

    def print_func2(self, name):
        print(name)

    def call_func_by_name(self):
        for func in self.func_list:
            getattr(self, func[1])('Func Name')

>>> myStringMethod().call_func_by_name()
Func Name
Func Name
```

Comment: still  no function get called

Answer (score 0):

maybe offtopic, but maybe your list is actually a dict :

```
self.functs = {'func1':'print_func1', ...}
```

and then call with  :

```
for fn in self.functs.values() : self.__dict__[fn]('Func Name')
```

or even if you wanted to call all 'func_' functions in your class (no func_list here) :

```
@classmethod
def call_func_by_name(cls)
  for n,f in cls.__dict__.values() : 
     if n.startswith('print_') and hasattr(f,'__call__'): f('Hello')
```